# Vue.js swap array items

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my vue.js application I'm trying to swap 2 forum rows like this:

```
export default {
        data() {
            return {
                forums: []
            }
        },

        methods: {
            increment(forum, index) {
                ForumService.increment(forum)
                    .then(() => {
                        let b = this.forums[index];
                        this.forums[index] = this.forums[index++];
                        this.forums[index++] = b;
                    });
            }
        }
    }
```

But nothing happens? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While @dfsq is correct about the use of `index++` Vue doesn't recognize native mutations of arrays due to the inability to observe them. you have to use a mutation method to change them.

try this:

```
.then(() => {
  let rows = [this.forums[index], this.forums[index + 1]];
  this.forums.splice(index, 2, rows[1], rows[0] );
});
```

I haven't tested it and I'll edit when I can.

Comment: This is correct about splice. However, `this.forums.splice(index, 2, this.forums[index + 1], this.forums[index]);` is enough.

Comment: @dfsq true, just a personal preference to save the values.

Comment: No, I mean your code won't work with array as third argument. Should be `this.forums.splice(index, 2, rows[1], rows[0] );`

Comment: Ah so your right. Thanks for noticing that I'll change it when I get home

Comment: Thanks - really like this approach, works perfectly :)